# How can I delay the action of a slider?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a jQuery UI slider that I'm using to adjust the brightness of an image. Since this involves requesting a new image from the server, things get kind of slow if, when dragged from 0 to 50, 50 new images are requested. I want to build in a delay so that it doesn't complete its action until the slider stops moving. How is this possible? I can't find any stop drag events.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/william/RSkpH/1/  Do you need something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the [`stop(event, ui)` event](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop) which is fired, when the sliding has stopped:

```
$(".selector").slider({
    stop: function(event, ui) {}
});
```